# how to set pagesize in special pages that i want to rotate just these pages!

Tags: c#, itext, rotation

I have a document in [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). I want to set the default 'pagesize' to 'A4', but here we have special pages that needed to be rotated (just these pages) using `A4.Rotate()`.

`document.setpagesize(A4.Rotate())` for the pages to be rotated.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Not too bad Hamid, at least I can understand what you meant and tidy it up a bit for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example. It creates a PDF file with 4 pages. Page 1,2 and 4 use A4 portrait mode while page 3 uses A4 landscape mode:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        using (var stream = new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            doc.Open();

            doc.NewPage();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page1 (portrait A4)"));

            doc.NewPage();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page2 (portrait  A4)"));

            // Set page size before calling NewPage
            doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            doc.NewPage();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page3 (landscape A4)"));
            // Revert to the original page size before adding new pages
            doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);

            doc.NewPage();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Page4 (portrait A4)"));

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
```